# Why is NumberOfMessagesDeleted > NumberOfMessagesSent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I don't understand the metrics for my SQS non-FIFO queue (images below) I'm looking at so I'm hoping someone can help me. The attached images show how I've configured the metrics and are the sum the number of messages sent and the number of messages deleted for the lifetime of this SQS queue (the queue is less than 1 week old but I've set the metrics period for 2 weeks).

It's my understanding that `NumberOfMessagesSent` refers to the number of messages that have been successfully enqueued and that `NumberOfMessagesDeleted` is the number of messages that have been successfully dequeued. Given that line of thinking I would think that `NumberOfMessagesDeleted` should always be <= than `NumberOfMessagesSent` but this is clearly not the case.

What am I missing here?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple consumers for the same queue?

Comment: I do not. I have one consumer makes receive message requests one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every message you consume you have a [receipt handle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-queue-message-identifiers.html#receipt-handle). You can call `DeleteMessage` using this handle multiple time, these calls are recorded successfully increasing the value for `NumberOfMessagesDeleted` metric.

In fact the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) provide 2 examples when will the `NumberOfMessagesDeleted` larger then expected:

1. In case of multiple consumers for the same queue:

> If the message is not processed before the visibility timeout expires, the message becomes available to other consumers that can process it and delete it again, increasing the value of the `NumberOfMessagesDeleted` metric.

2. Calling `DeleteMessage` multiple times for the same message:

> If the message is processed and deleted but you call the `DeleteMessage` action again using the same receipt handle, a success status is returned, increasing the value of the NumberOfMessagesDeleted metric.

The second one may occur if you have a bug in your code. For example, the library used automatically deletes the message after it is received, but you are also attempt to delete the message manually.

Furthermore, non-FIFO SQS queues may encounter message duplications, which can also increase the number of messages deleted.

Comment: Ah, I see. After reading more into the docs you linked I'm thinking this is probably what's happening:

"Calling the DeleteMessage action on different receipt handles that belong to the same message: If the message is not processed before the visibility timeout expires, the message becomes available to other consumers that can process it and delete it again, increasing the value of the NumberOfMessagesDeleted metric"

Thank you!